# multiple pivots in one select statement

Tags: sql, pivot

I am trying to use multiple pivot statements within one select statement, but its giving me errors like the following for all the attributes:

`The multi-part identifier "pvt.[attributeName]" could not be bound.`

My query is as such:

```
SELECT pvt.*, pvt2.COG
FROM (Select ......) AS SRC
PIVOT(
MAX([preValueDesc]) FOR [preDesc] IN ([3rd Party], [First Email Campaign], [Second Email Campaign], [First Mail Campaign], [Second Mail Campaign])) pvt
PIVOT(
max([attributeValue]) FOR [attributeDesc] IN ([COG])) pvt2
```

I am not sure where I can go from here

Comment: When you are using multiple pivot you can use only the last pivot alias name.

Comment: ohh so if i use pvt2 it ll ass work?

Comment: ahh that worked. Thank you very much mate, I should have known that lol. Having a moment of stupidity